# Testing image's 'naturalHeight' without DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm writing a JS test to check that an image's css class is being applied properly. The class is computed based on the image's `naturalHeight` property. However, because this is a JS test, there is no DOM, so `naturalHeight` is always 0 in testing. How can I properly test/mock this using Jest and Enzyme?

Simplified version of component:

```
class Image extends React.Component {
    public render () {
    return (
      <img 
        src={this.props.src}
        ref={el => this.imageElement = el } 
        className={ this._computeStyle() }/>
    )
  }

  private _computeStyle() {
    if (this.imageElement.naturalHeight > 100){ 
      return 'big';
    }
    return 'small'
  }
}
```

Trying to test:

```
it('has class "big" if > 100 pixels', () => {
  let wrapper = mount(<Image src={largeImage} />);
  expect(wrapper.find('img').hasClass('big')).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `jsdom` doesn't actually render the document, size properties are usually not implemented and return a fixed 0.

In the case of `naturalHeight`, it [seems](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/blob/2d51af302581a57ee5b9b65595f1714d669b7ea2/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/HTMLImageElement-impl.js#L73) like it actually falls back to the `height` property.

I therefore see two options:

**1. Manually assign `height`:**

```
wrapper.find('img').node.height = 120;
```

**2. Extend the prototype of `HTMLImageElement`:**

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLImageElement.prototype, 'naturalHeight', { get: () => 120 });
```

Comment: Thank you! Extending the prototype worked. Would this change be scoped to this test, or will it define the property globally for all tests in the project?

Comment: It will only affect this specific test file